# Getting an equality test to work with char's and an array

Tags: java, string, character, equality

I've been given the task to create a method that takes in a single char and does an equality check to see if it matches any char in an array.

For the number of times that a match is found, a counter is supposed to go up. I'm pretty sure that the syntax on the for loop is correct, but I have no idea how to run the equality check.

`if(tiles.toCharArray()==letter)` is my current attempt. Any thoughts on how I could switch out or change this line of code to get the equality test to work?

```
public class ScrabblePlayer {

  private String tiles;
  int count;

  // A String representing all of the tiles that this player has
  public char ScrabblePlayer() {
    tiles = "";
  }

  public int getCountOfLetter(char letter) {
    count = 0;
    for(char character : tiles.toCharArray()) {
    if(tiles.toCharArray() == letter);
    count += 1;
  }
  return count;
}
```

Comment: You have a stray semicolon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `getCountOfLetter` method code you have two problems:

1. The useless semicolon `;` in the end of the `if` condition line.
2. And you are using the wrong variable in the `if` condition, `tiles.toCharArray()` should be replaced with `character`, as you are looping over it.

This is how should be your code:

```
public int getCountOfLetter(char letter) {
    count = 0;
    for(char character : tiles.toCharArray()) {
        if(character == letter)
           count ++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be this:-

```
if(character == letter) {
    count += 1;
}
```

On a side note, I think `public char ScrabblePlayer()` should maybe be `public ScrabblePlayer()` if it's supposed to be the constructor.